# asp.net c# login type

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can anyone help me with this problem.

I've use 2 login buttons which is for members and admin... I have assigned `Response.Cookies["DBBRoles"].Value = "M";` for members and `Response.Cookies["DBBRoles"].Value = "A";` for Admin on login.aspx... and i also put these            `Response.Write(Request.Cookies["DBBRoles"].Value.ToString());` on the page when the user has successfully login into the system.

The problem is why the the system still keep the Value 'A' for admin even though i login as a members.and i can login the system with the same username and password with 1 button... it didn't check the login type for admin or members.

Comment: Why aren't you using [Role based authorization](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/roles/role-based-authorization-cs) ?

Comment: Be careful putting unprotected authentication evidence in cookies. Anyone can create a file of the cookie name in the Cookies folder containing "A" and impersonate an Admin. Consider using secure cookies and signing or encrypting the cookie contents.

Comment: You should use ASP.NET Membership and Role Providers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear your cache, cookies and sessions every test you did. If not, you are appending values to the same cookie each test and depend of your login implementation, if not clear cache, cookies and sessions, you have persistent data as your session still are running.

Comment: thanks @Alberto León! Sometimes it's just a simple problems but we not alerts with it.

Comment: @Kyla the longest problem normally is a small and simple thing. In my 11 years programming, all problems that taked more than 1 hour were problems like this, one letter forgotten in the name of a var,...